# grails cxf access soap headers

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

is there a way to access soap headers within a cxf service class in grails? you know that you can access the whole soap message with interceptors, but i need header direct in the service class. any ideas?

Comment: have a look at: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/cxf-plugin-access-soap-headers-td3242467.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `@Resource private WebServiceContext context` field to the service source code, and then you'll be able to use something like `context.messageContext.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST).remoteAddr` to get headers.

Comment: if you have a look on the post in the grails mailing list I mentioned above, you will see the solution with WebServiceContext was already described. Furthermore another solution would be to use a special cxf interceptor called ReadHeadersInterceptor. This class provides a method called handleMessage. There you can easily access the headers by calling message.getHeaders().